# How to efficiently make changes to code (removing defunct code)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got an ASP.NET web application, that is essentially our intranet site.  I made a lot of progress on the administration office's employee management pages.  It ties into an SQL server database, and I'm using a three layered design (Objects, Logic, DataAccess).  It was all reviewed and all of it was accepted, except! for the part that manages vacations and vacation histories.

My question, before I go into details is, how does one efficiently "untangle" code that is no longer necessary?

For example: previously I was treating each VacationDay as it's own entity with it's own history.  Such that I could track the history of an individual day.  To help in tracking, I have an enum called VacationDayAction, which includes options such as .Submitted, .RequestDenied, .CancellationRequested, and so on.  This was in an attempt to provide meticulous detail for each day.  It was then determined that we no longer need that.  We do, however, still need VacationDays and all the basic functions of that (saving days, getting days, etc.), but now we no longer need any of the "history" related classes.

My problem is, when I right click a class that I no longer need in VS and go to "Show All References," I get a ton of results scattered across several pages.  I need to get rid of all of them, without breaking the rest of the application.  Is there not some kind of "smart" technique or method for easily untangling parts that are no longer necessary?  This is particularly difficult because 90% of what I did was just fine, and needs to stay like it is.  Yet scattered in that 90% is 10% of stuff that is no longer needed.  I can't just go storming through with the delete key either, because with the removal of each reference, I need to be sure that any dependencies on that reference are also fixed in a way that they don't call stuff that isn't there anymore.  And I still need the application is a compilable state, so that I can test along the way that the rest of the application didn't fall apart as a result of some deletion.

To give you an idea of my low level of experience, I started two years ago with having never used C#, ASP.Net, or Visual Studio.  It blew my mind when, way after starting and as I was learning, someone taught me that I could use breakpoints.  And then it really really blew my mind when I learned about multi-layered design.  I'm wondering if there is not some technique or trick or feature that can help in scenarios like this, where you have to "untangle" and throw away unnecessary stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a simple question. In fact, I would say this is one of the major challenges for any systems developer; how to handle and get rid of old code which is not in use. There is lots of literature on this, and few really excellent answers. A good book may be "**Working effectively with legacy code**" by Michael Feathers, which deals with many related problems. It is no light read though, and will probably take some time to get through, but it will likely help you become a better coder, and better at these kinds of tasks in particular.

Maybe you can have a look at the Resharper tool? ( http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ ) It is a productivity tool which among other things shows "dead" code (unused code) in grey, and lets you remove it. It will also help you remove unused references from each class (again, they will be grayed out and let you remove them automatically).

Drawing diagrams where each major piece of code /component is a box with a line linking it to any related component might help you get a better overview; try to draw a hierarchy showing how different parts of the code are related and dependent.

The bottom line as far as I know, is that you just have to muddle through it, commenting out code a little at a time, then recompiling and testing it. If it still works, fine, now you can remove the commented out code completely. This would be easier if you had unit-tests covering your code, but I take it as a given that you don't, as is unfortunately often the case.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly the kind of info I was looking for.  Thanks!